# Power BI - Latest date selected as default on Live connection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating a Power BI report using a live connection. I am trying to have the latest date selected as default. There is a way to do this with a calculated column but there is no way I can create a calculated column since it's using a live connection. Is there a way around this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the latest date for each row that has multiple dates? I have a push dataset that has historical data, which uses a measure to restrict all data except for the newest for each account. Is that similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello! It's the latest date within the whole dataset.